# How to see source code of a fun in Kotlin in Android Studio 3.1.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I hope to see the source code of the fun `let`, but I get the following content after I <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click `data?.let`.

How to see the source code of a fun in Kotlin in Android Studio 3.1.3?

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly public inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R { /* compiled code */ }
```

**Added Content**

[image: Added Content]

[image: Android studio start]

**And More**

The image when I click on choose sources

[image: kotlin jar image]

**Solved:**

Now it's OK when system updates the Kotlin plugin today.

I think that the system update the plugin failed caused the problem.

How can I update the plugin manually? You know the Update Plugin UI doesn't always be displayed by the system!

[image]

Comment: If you want to import sources like that, import the jar that ends with `-sources`, it's in one of the other two directories. Jar without suffix contains compiled classes.

Comment: Go to `File | Settings | Plugins` (or use `find action...`) and search for the `Kotlin`-plugin. If an update is available, you can update it also there manually. Usually however you get appropriate notifications automatically and just need to tell that you want to update all plugins. I had a similar problem once too, but I don't know what I did, nor what caused the problem. Probably it also disappeared with an update or upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the source code of `let` in `kotlin-stdlib-common-1.2.51.jar` where path is `kotlin -> Standard.kt (or file name showing as StandardKt.kotlin_metadata)`. I am doing same command.

Below is code of that `fun`

```
/**
 * Calls the specified function [block] with `this` value as its argument and returns its result.
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    return block(this)
}
```

---

Versions I am using are

```
Android Studio 3.1.3
Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 4, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.6

And kotlin version is Version: 1.2.51-release-Studio3.1-1
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?  I can't get it when I click `.let` key using Ctrl+Click in Windows 7 64bit OS + Android Studio.

Comment: @HelloCW What is version of kotlin?

Comment: @HelloCW At attached screenshot you are getting option to download "source code". Try that option.

Comment: None after I click "Download Sources" button.

Comment: @HelloCW Can you please share your gradle config only kotlin related entries

Comment: You can see it at
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgrrh5x5igelhcs/build.gradle.txt?dl=0

  and

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yh8c11q79fif8j7/build_A.gradle.txt?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176847/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-hellocw).